# Ubuntu has trouble with this particular HDMI projector. Fedora is fine. Eh?

Tags: gnome, kernel, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

I posted this on the forums but didn't get any hits, figured I'd try here. Anyway, I'm trying (and so far, failing) to find a solution to an issue I'm having. Some context, we have an assortment of different projectors, all HDMI, and an assortment of laptop hardware. The problematic projector in question is an InFocus IN126STa. What happens is when I plug in via HDMI, it picks up a signal from the laptop and I'll see something (sometimes it's extended mode, other times it's mirror), but the problem comes in when I switch modes -- say extended mode versus mirror. Almost all of the time, trying to switch the mode one time results in the InFocus projector going blank. The laptop however seems to respond as if it acknowledges the projector. I see the InFocus entry in display settings, I see the resolution, the framerate, the make/model, etc. It's just... nothing appears on the screen after trying to switch modes. I've tried this with other model projectors (namely Epson and NEC) but haven't ran into these issues.

The laptop hardware in question was tested on a Lenovo T470, Lenovo E570, and an Acer Travelmate TM113. The E570 is the almighty target machine to try and get working (hence why there's more mention of E570 below), but the Acer and T470 were just to compare. A rough list of what I've tried:

1. T470 with Ubuntu (Unity) 16.04 with Xorg
2. T470 with Ubuntu (Gnome) 16.04 with Xorg
3. E570 with Ubuntu (Gnome) 17.10 with Xorg
4. E570 with Ubuntu (Gnome) 17.10 with Wayland
5. Acer Travelmate TM113 with Ubuntu (Unity) 16.04 with Xorg
6. Three different types of HDMI cables
7. Upgrading the BIOS on the E570 to the latest version
8. Upgrading the firmware on the InFocus projector to the latest version
9. On the E570 with Ubuntu (Gnome) 17.10, I've tried the current Ubuntu kernel v4.13 along with the mainline 4.14 kernel and the mainline 4.15 kernel
10. Installed Antergos (Gnome) on the E570 and updated everything

All of the above resulted in the same experience: no change, problem still existed.

Here's where things got interesting... a colleague runs Fedora 27 with Gnome on a T470, so we tested that. Boom, worked fine. After that, I installed Fedora 27 with Gnome on the E570. Again, worked fine. The problem simply went away on Fedora. Projection with the InFocus projectors was a very consistent, stable experience.

At this point I'm trying to figure out what's different in the way Fedora 27 may handle Intel video on the E570/T470 than how Ubuntu/Antergos handle it. Something about Fedora is making this a far better experience, but given our target OS is Ubuntu, it makes me wonder what on earth it could be.

Based on this information, does anybody have any suggestions or further ideas to try? I appreciate any and all answers.

Comment: You'd be better off on [unix.se] as you'll find people knowing both Fedora 27 and Ubuntu.  Anyway, what's the output to `uname -a` and `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` on the Fedora and the #4 machine in your list?  Ping me @Fabby with this info...

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Fabby. Makes sense about the Unix and Linux page. I'll definitely do that. In the mean time I have my paste output here. https://paste.ubuntu.com/26510888/ Everything is identical except the Mesa version (17.2.2 vs 17.2.4). :(

Comment: As I expected...  Try the [X-Team's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates) to update your mesa drivers.  **Make a system backup before you start!**  If that solves your problem, I'll post an answer.  Please ping me again (for both hit or miss, please).

Comment: I'll give it a shot for sure. I'd be a little surprised if that would make a difference given Fedora, which works, is on the slightly older version of mesa. I was meaning to test the current build of 18.04 for comparison sake too just to see. I won't have access to the projector until Monday but I'll surely give it a try. In the meantime this is kind of a research weekend. Thanks much!

Comment: If it doesn't work, I'll flag your question for migration to [unix.se].